# Cant import ovpn file - Key file contains "client" which is not a key-value pair

Tags: vpn, openvpn

When I try to import the `VPN` settings from an `OVPN` file, I get the following error.

> The file "test.ovpn" could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information.
>   Error: Key file contains line "client" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment

I am quite sure that the line "client" should not be a problem, since I have it in other `.ovpn` files as well.

What is wrong with this?

PS: This is the beginning of the ovpn file (with fake data)

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote xxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.de 443
verify-x509-name "C=de, L=Somewhere, O=mycompanyname AG, CN=xxxxx.yyyyyyyy.de, emailAddress=admins@yyyyyyyyy.de"
route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth MD5
comp-lzo no
route-delay 4
verb 3
reneg-sec 0
```

Comment: can you share with us the `.ovpn` file, I assume that we might find the problematic line there

Comment: Not sure I am allowed to show you that... I will try to put some lines with dummy data

Comment: I have updated with some (hopefully) relevant info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633337) in **NetworkManager** : *configuration files with inline certificates can't be imported*.

There are several workarounds which can be taken:

1. Use the [this python script](https://gist.github.com/seebk/bb94a7fd70d4cc454aaa) which extract the embedded certificates and rewrite the ovpn config to use separate key and cert files. ([reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365))
2. Execute the `ovpn` config using command line:

   ```
   sudo openvpn your-ovpn-config-filename.ovpn
   ```
3. separate lines which contains `port` into several lines:

   ```
   remote xxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.de 443
   ```

   To be:

   ```
   remote xxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.de 
   port 443
   ```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I extracted the certificates via that script and now I get `Error: Key file contains line "ca ca.crt" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment.`. Why is NM so bloody incompetent at importing OVPN files?

Comment: BTW the new tracking location for this bug seems [to be here on GNOME GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/-/issues/11).

Comment: yes, I extracted the file but still getting same error as @DoktorJ

Answer (score 2):

Could be because of `mssfix 0` option. Per NM's opinion it's wrong. How to check which option is not acceptable? Try from terminal:

```
# nmcli connection import type openvpn file client1_udp.ovpn
[sudo] password for ipeacocks: 
Error: failed to import 'client1_udp.ovpn': configuration error: invalid 1th argument to “mssfix” where number expected (line 136).
```

Link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365/comments/95

Answer (score 1):

I've solved very same issue when Network Manager was complaining about very first line of .ovpn file but it appeared the error was misleading and wasnot actual reason. The actual reson was that both my **~/.cert** and **.cert/nm-openvpn/** folders were owned by **root** within standard user home folder. This might happen be when you've run **openvpn** command line with **sudo** in past. So it seems like something is broken on the way between Gnome and openvpn
`sudo chown -R user:user ~/.cert` did the job.